# ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis pd.concat

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

i am trying to concatenate a pandas dataframe:

```
def extract_articles(data, article_numbers):
  result = pd.concat(
     [
        data[data['ARTICLENO'] == article_no]['QUANTITY']
        for article_no in article_numbers
     ],
     axis=1,
  ).fillna(0)
  result.columns = article_numbers
  return result
```

When reading more lines (about 100k) from the csv i get the following error:
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Here is how my csv basically looks like:

```
Date,       ArticleNo, Quantity
2018-07-15, 1005,      150
2018-07-14, 1005,      165
2018-07-12, 1005,      160
2018-07-14, 1008,      230
2018-07-12, 1008,      245
```

The file is sorted by article number and date. For each date it is possible to have multiple 'article number-quantity-tuples' There can be gaps where some of the article numbers have no data, they are 0.
Why do i get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are duplicated index values, you can change:

```
data[data['ARTICLENO'] == article_no]['QUANTITY']
```

to

```
(data.loc[data['ARTICLENO'] == article_no, ['QUANTITY']]
      .set_index(data.groupby('Date').cumcount(), append=True))
```

for `MultiIndex`.

But for your expected output need aggregate `sum` and reshape by `unstack`:

```
df = df.groupby(['Date','ArticleNo'])['Quantity'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
ArticleNo   1005  1008
Date                  
2018-07-12   160   245
2018-07-14   165   230
2018-07-15   150     0
```

Comment: but i need the date as index for futher processing

Comment: @ItFreak - Answer is edited, problem is duplicated `Date`s per `ArticleNo`

Comment: this is giving me a series which has no method set_index

Comment: thanks, that works but i would prefer a dataframe with the article numbers in the columns and the quantities for each from top to down, date as index and for each date where an article number has no value i would prefer a zero.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, that worked! The only problem I have: if an article number got its fiirst entry at 2016-01-01 and the dataframe "starts" at 2015-01-01: How can I remove the article numbers that are 0 through the complete year 2015? You understand what I mean? (Background: I need to cluster the frame with kmeans and therefore i need always one year of data so i only want to use the values of e.g. 2015)

Comment: @ItFreak - So need filter output DataFrame by years? like `df.loc['2015']` or `df.loc['2016']` ? Or need something else?

Comment: actually i use df.loc['2015-01-01' : '2015-12-31'] to get all that are in 2015. But with the new solution, all article numbers are in 2015, cause they are filled with zeros, you knwo what i mean?

Comment: @ItFreak - hmmm, I think there has to be at least non zero value per row, but is possible there is only one value, so if many columns it is not easy find.

Comment: i just want to avoid to have a lot of 'zeros' in my final cluster (okey, if it works correctly, they are all in one cluster but thats not well enough for me : D)

Comment: @ItFreak - Yes, but it is more data problem, do you think is possible remove columns by number of `0` ?

Comment: yes it is indeed a data problem, but i think 10 ore more continous zeros are a clear sign for 'fake' values. They need to be removed because i cluster on percentage change of pandas and i get division by zero errors if there are too many zeris

Comment: @ItFreak - It is realy complicated, but I try add solution

Comment: @ItFreak - Hmmm, I try working with sample data `np.random.seed(2000)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], size=(20, 18), p=(.8,.2)))`, problem is if filter by 10 consecutive 0 in row then all columns has to be removed and i think it is not what need. I think same problem in your data. What do you think?

Comment: didnt try hat, but is it possible with pandas to interpolate a 0 value? so if there is one or two zeros beyond each other interpolate the value from before and after?

Comment: @ItFreak - Yes, it is possible, only need change zeros to `NaN`s by removing parameter `fill_value=0` like `df.groupby(['Date','ArticleNo'])['Quantity'].sum().unstack()` and then use [`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html)